# How to get playlist name(title) with youtube-dl

Tags: fedora, bash-scripting, youtube, youtube-dl

I have an issue with youtube-dl in Linux, so I want to create a bash
script letting me download a playlist and put all the videos in a
separate folder having the name of that playlist
here is my attempt :

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Enter the URL of the playlist : '
read url
title = youtube-dl -o "%(title)s \"$url\""
mkdir "$title"
cd $title
youtube-dl --download-archive archive.txt $url
```

but it always gives this error :

```
[gerzal@dhcppc1 Videos]$ ./try.bash
Enter the URL of the playlist :
ff
youtube-dl -o %(title)s "ff"
./try.bash: line 6: title: command not found
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘’: No such file or directory
```

thanks in advance for help and it will be really appreciated.

***update information:***

I contacted one of the youtube-dl developers and he gave me the solution in one command line without adding mkdir command, here is the command line:

```
youtube-dl --download-archive archive.txt -o '%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s' "$url"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the -o option with **yt-dlp** command to customize the output file name

- For **Index** : %(playlist_index)s
- For **Title** : %(title)s
- For **Youtuber name** : %(uploader)s
- For **Video Id** : %(id)s

---

```
yt-dlp -i -o "%(playlist_index)s-%(title)s-%(uploader)s-%(id)s" --get-filename --skip-download --no-warnings youtube_link
```